# Conditional loop in python

Tags: python

```
list=['a','a','x','c','e','e','f','f','f']

i=0
count = 0

while count < len(list)-2:
    if list[i] == list[i+1]:
        if list [i+1] != list [i+2]:
            print list[i]
            i+=1
            count +=1
        else:print "no"
    else:   
        i +=1
        count += 1
```

I'm getting:

```
    else:print "no"
   ^
 IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

I'm trying to only print the elts that match the following element, but not the element following that. I'm new to Python, and I'm not sure why this isn't working.

Comment: have you pasted your code exactly ? Because there is no error in this piece of code.

Comment: make sure you do not mix in tabs with spaces. Also, have the `if` and `else` at the same indentation level. Also, dont use `list` as a variable name, as it is a builtin type

Comment: Avoid the use of `list`, since that's a defined internal function (and overriding it will cause problems).

Comment: Also, using a for-loop instead of a while-loop will make all of this a little easier.

Comment: @Makoto, that's wrong in three aspects: `list` is a built-in type and not a function; you don't override it but simply shadow the name in the scope of the variable; and it doesn't directly cause problems unless you also want to reference the type in the same scope. The actual problem with using `list` as a variable name is that it is a very indescriptive name, that it could confuse people reading the code if they don't see it is shadowed, and that it stops python and tools like pyflakes from warning you about undefined variables and also could make it harder to find bugs.

Comment: @l4mpi "referencing the type in the same scope" [is more common than you might expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31087111), especially when that's the global scope (as could easily happen in an interpreter session).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the fixed-up code (added a `count += 1` after the else-clause to make sure it terminates):

```
list=['a','a','x','c','e','e','f','f','f']

i=0
count = 0

while count < len(list)-2:
    if list[i] == list[i+1]:
        if list [i+1] != list [i+2]:
            print list[i]
            i+=1
            count +=1
        else:
            print "no"
            count += 1
    else:   
        i +=1
        count += 1
```

A more advanced solution using [*itertools*](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is more compact and easier to get right:

```
from itertools import groupby

data = ['a','a','x','c','e','e','f','f','f']
for k, g in groupby(data):
    if len(list(g)) > 1:
        print k
```

Comment: This also shows why you shouldn't use `list` as a variable name

Comment: It also appears that the itertools version catches more conditions (example the 'f' isn't printed using the while loop). Also, the original loop prints nothing if the list is modified to contain three 'a's at once (i is never incremented).

Comment: Wow itertools is a great solution. Just replacing the ">" with "==" gives me exactly what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The code works for me without error (although you get stuck in a loop). Make sure you are not mixing tabs and spaces.

Comment: I'd argue that getting stuck in a loop constitutes an error of some kind.

Comment: The loop has nothing to do with the question and I've pointed it out. The question at hand is regarding the unexpected indent.