# Has set been deprecated in python 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Has `set` been deprecated in python?

I am learning python online [here](http://www.python-course.eu/sets_frozensets.php) and trying to implement the following command -

```
x = set(["Perl", "Python", "Java"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

So has it been deprecated in python 2.7?

Comment: Works fine for me. Looks like you masked `set`.

Comment: No, it hasn't - somewhere, you've assigned a list to the name `set`.

Comment: Typical name shadowing. There are a hell lot of duplicates out there. People should really start off by downloading PyCharm. That would eliminate 90% of newbie question on SO, provided they would pay attention to warnings.

Comment: There are set literals `{1,2,3}`, which do work. Further, why don't you learn Python 3? That said, I can't reproduce your behaviour.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'list' object is not callable in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31087111/typeerror-list-object-is-not-callable-in-python)

Comment: @Tushar It doesn't really matter, because both questions have this error `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable` caused by identical reasons. And there are tons of these questions on SO.

Comment: @EliKorvigo - Technically, that question is about trying to call `list()` while this one is about trying to call `set()`. Personally, I agree that it's the exact same problem with the exact same solution, differing only in variable names, but some believe that that makes it not a duplicate. If that question were more like "I'm trying to call a built-in function but it isn't acting like one," it would be more broadly applicable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you assigned some list to a variable named `set`, and now the `set` in `set(["Perl", "Python", "Java"])` refers to that variable. If you're in interactive mode, do `del set` or restart your interpreter to get rid of your variable and go back to the built-in `set`. If this is a script, pick a different variable name.