# Python: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable on global variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am currently in the process of programming a text-based adventure in Python as a learning exercise. I want "help" to be a global command, stored as values in a list, that can be called at (essentially) any time. As the player enters a new room, or the help options change, I reset the `help_commands` list with the new values. However, when I debug the following script, I get a  `'list' object is not callable` TypeError.

I have gone over my code time and time again and can't seem to figure out what's wrong. I'm somewhat new to Python, so I assume it's something simple I'm overlooking.

```
player = {
    "name": "",
    "gender": "",
    "race": "",
    "class": "",
    "HP": 10,
}

global help_commands
help_commands = ["Save", "Quit", "Other"]

def help():
    sub_help = '|'.join(help_commands)
    print "The following commands are avalible: " + sub_help


def help_test():
    help = ["Exit [direction], Open [object], Talk to [Person], Use [Item]"]
    print "Before we go any further, I'd like to know a little more about you."
    print "What is your name, young adventurer?"
    player_name = raw_input(">> ").lower()
    if player_name == "help":
        help()
    else:
        player['name'] = player_name
        print "It is nice to meet you, ", player['name'] + "."

help_test()
```

Edit:

You're like my Python guru, Moses. That fixed my problem, however now I can't get the values in help_commands to be overwritten by the new commands:

```
player = {
    "name": "",
    "gender": "",
    "race": "",
    "class": "",
    "HP": 10,
}

# global help_commands
help_commands = ["Save", "Quit", "Other"]

def help():
    sub_help = ' | '.join(help_commands)
    return "The following commands are avalible: " + sub_help


def help_test():
    print help()
    help_commands = ["Exit [direction], Open [object], Talk to [Person], Use [Item]"]
    print help()
    print "Before we go any further, I'd like to know a little more about you."
    print "What is your name, young adventurer?"
    player_name = raw_input(">> ").lower()
    if player_name == "help":
        help()
    else:
        player['name'] = player_name
        print "It is nice to meet you, ", player['name'] + "."

help_test()
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'list' object is not callable in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31087111/typeerror-list-object-is-not-callable-in-python)

Comment: Global has nothing to do with it. `help = ["Exit [direction], Open [object], Talk to [Person], Use [Item]"]` and after that `help()` - it tries to call list instance.

Comment: Post the stack trace, not just the error message. The stack trace tells us which line failed so we don't have to search for it.

Comment: In your edit, you are creating a new, local variable called help_commands, but the global help is not being changed. You can fix this by starting with `global help_commands` as a line before you assign it, but it would be better to create an object to hold both the function (method) and the list, or provide the list as an argument to the function.

Comment: You _are_ using the`global` statement incorrectly, but that is irrelevant to this error. You don't need `global` to access a global variable, only when you want to reassign a global, and when you need that, you put the `global` statement in the function that's doing the re-assigning. But it's best to avoid re-assigning to globals, there's almost always a better way to organize the logic.

Comment: @Keozon - Wow, thanks! As I said, I'm new to Python so I likely wouldn't have thought of that. Objects are one of the things I'm less skilled in; would it be possible to see an example of how you think it should be done?

Comment: That's a different question! Please don't make significant changes to your questions like that after they've already got a good answer. Ask a new question instead. Or for minor stuff, just ask in the comments on the answer.

Comment: Ooops! Sorry about that! I'll ask another question instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing the name of a list with that of a function:

```
help = ["Exit [direction], Open [object], Talk to [Person], Use [Item]"]
```

And then:

```
def help():
    sub_help = '|'.join(help_commands)
    print "The following commands are avalible: " + sub_help
```

The name `help` in the current scope (which references a list) is being treated as a callable, which is not the case.

Consider *renaming* the list or better still, both, since the name `help` is already being used by a builtin function.

Comment: I would advise to change the function name `help` to `print_help` to avoid any issue with the native Python keyword.