# Python: Locally assigning values to a global list

Tags: python, python-2.7, object

I am currently in the process of programming a text-based adventure in Python as a learning exercise. I want "help" to be a global command, stored as values in a list, that can be called at (essentially) any time. As the player enters a new room, or the help options change, I reset the help_commands list with the new values. However, for some reason I cannot get the values in `help_commands` to update *inside* a function.

I asked a similar question before ([Python: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable on global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38510214/python-typeerror-list-object-is-not-callable-on-global-variable)) and was suggested an object might be the way for me to go.

I'm somewhat new to Python and objects are one of my weaker aspects, so could I possibly get an example from someone?

```
player = {
    "name": "",
    "gender": "",
    "race": "",
    "class": "",
    "HP": 10,
}

# global help_commands
help_commands = ["Save", "Quit", "Other"]

def help():
    sub_help = ' | '.join(help_commands)
    return "The following commands are avalible: " + sub_help


def help_test():
    print help()
    help_commands = ["Exit [direction], Open [object], Talk to [Person], Use [Item]"]
    print help()
    print "Before we go any further, I'd like to know a little more about you."
    print "What is your name, young adventurer?"
    player_name = raw_input(">> ").lower()
    if player_name == "help":
        help()
    else:
        player['name'] = player_name
        print "It is nice to meet you, ", player['name'] + "."

help_test()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's creating a local variable with the same name as the global variable.  All in all, it's not a very great way to program - you might want to have a global help object, instead... or not.  In any event, in your help_test() function, start with:

```
global(help_commands)
```

And see if that does what you want.

This happens in objects, too.... there's a difference between:

```
foo = "something"
```

and

```
self.foo = "something"
```

inside a member function.  If you're coming from something like visual basic, concepts like these will royally screw you up (luckily I went the other way, and just shake my head at VB).

Comment: I think VB results in head shaking from many. Thank you for your help!