# Removing an item from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to remove to ignore duplicates in my list. For example, let's say the function checks for words that end with a ''.'' and puts them in a list. I would like to make sure that duplicate words don't go in the list.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def endwords(sent):
    list = []
    words = sent.split()
    for word in words:
        if "." in word:
            list.append(word)
        # bottom if statment does not work for some reason. thats the one i am trying to fix    
        if (word == list):
            list.remove(word)
    return list
```

Comment: you should avoid using names of built-ins for your objects (like `list`, `dict`, `str`, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you check if the word is already in the list before appending it, like so:

```
def endwords(sent):
     wordList = []
     words = sent.split()
     for word in words:
         if "." in word and word not in wordList:
             wordList.append(word)
     return wordList
```

You're trying to check if `word == list`, but that's seeing if the word is equal to the entire list. To check if an element is in a container in python, you can use the `in` keyword. Alternatively, to check if something is not in a container, you can use `not in`.

Another option is to use a set:

```
def endwords(sent):
     wordSet = set()
     words = sent.split()
     for word in words:
         if "." in word:
             wordSet.add(word)
     return wordSet
```

And to make things a little cleaner, here is a version using set comprehension:

```
def endwords(sent):
    return {word for word in sent.split() if '.' in word}
```

If you want to get a list out of this function, you can do so like this:

```
def endwords(sent):
    return list({word for word in sent.split() if '.' in word})
```

Since you said in your question you want to check if the word ends with a '.', you probably also want to use the endswith() function like so:

```
def endwords(sent):
    return list({word for word in sent.split() if word.endswith('.')})
```

Answer (score 2):

After statement

```
list = []
```

you can't use built-in [`list` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists) and to understand that you can spend about an hour or so, that's why we avoid names of built-ins for our objects.

More at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31087151/5997596).

---

> function checks for words that end with a ''.''

Statement

```
"." in word
```

checks if `word` contains dot symbol (e.g. `"." in "sample.text"` will work ok while it simply doesn't end with dot), if you need to check that it ends with dot – use `str.endswith` method.

---

> I would like to make sure that duplicate words don't go in the list.

just make sure before storing one that it hasn't been stored already.

---

Finally we can write

```
def endwords(sent, end='.'):
    unique_words = []
    words = sent.split()
    for word in words:
        if word.endswith(end) and word not in unique_words:
            unique_words.append(word)
    return unique_words
```

## Test

```
>>>sent = ' '.join(['some.', 'oth.er'] * 10)
>>>unique_words = endwords(sent)
>>>unique_words
['some.']
```

## P. S.

If order doesn't matter – use `set`, it will take care of duplicates (works only with hashable types, `str` is hashable):

```
def endwords(sent, end='.'):
    unique_words = set()
    words = sent.split()
    for word in words:
        if word.endswith(end) and word not in unique_words:
            unique_words.add(word)
    return unique_words
```

or with set comprehension

```
def endwords(sent, end='.'):
    words = sent.split()
    return {word for word in words if word.endswith(end)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a sample judge for the question.

```
def endwords(sent):
    list = []
    words = sent.split()
    for word in words:
        if "." in word:
            if word not in list:
                list.append(word)
        # bottom if statment does not work for some reason. thats the one i am trying to fix   

    return list
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a set?

```
def endwords(sent):
    my_list = set()
    words = sent.split()
    for word in words:
        if "." in word:
            my_list.add(word)
    return my_list
```

Answer (score 0):

The less verbose way to do it would be using list comprehension, that is

```
my_list = [word for word in words if '.' in word]
```

And to ensure the elements aren't duplicated, just use `set`.

```
my_list = set(my_list)  # No more duplicated values
```