# removing duplicates from a bool list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get a word in a list that is followed by a word with a ''.'' in it. for example, if this is a list

```
test_list = ["hello", "how", "are.", "you"]
```

it would select the word ''you'' I have managed to pull this off but I am trying to ensure that I do not get duplicate words. 
Here is what I have so far

```
list = []
i = 0
bool = False
words = sent.split()
for word in words:
    if bool:
        list.append(word)
        bool = False
   # the bellow if statment seems to make everything worse instead of fixing the duplicate problem
    if "." in word and word not in list:
        bool = True
return list
```

Comment: Please don't name your list `list` and a Boolean value `bool`....

Comment: `that is followed by a word with a ''.'' in it.` I assume you mean that follows a word with a `.` in it?

Comment: you need to preserve order?

Comment: To complete @abccd comment; `list` and `bool` are both names Python uses. They are reserved keywords for certain built in functions. You shouldn't overwrite these.

Comment: please, check [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44360560/5997596) to your previous question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't based off of the code you posted, however it should do exactly what you're asking.

```
def get_word_after_dot(words):
    for index, word in enumerate(words):
        if word.endswith('.') and len(words) - index > 1:
            yield words[index + 1]
```

Iterating over this generator will yield words that are followed by a period.

Answer (score 3):

Your whole code can be reduced to this example using `zip()` and `list comprehension`:

```
a = ['hello', 'how', 'are.', 'you']

def get_new_list(a):
    return [v for k,v in zip(a, a[1:]) if k.endswith('.')]
```

Then, to remove the duplicates, if there is any, you can use `set()`, like this example:

```
final = set(get_new_list(a))
```

output:

```
{'you'}
```

Comment: I don't think this is what he wants. He wants the words which appear _after_ a word with a dot. Your simply filtering the words with dots out.

Comment: @ChristianDean, I think now it's okay.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach to the same problem.

```
import itertools
from collections import deque

t = deque(map(lambda x: '.' in x, test_list)) # create a deque of bools
>>deque([False, False, True, False])

t.rotate(1) # shift it by one since we want the word after the '.'
>>deque([False, False, False, True])

set(itertools.compress(test_list, t)) # and then grab everywhere it is True
>>{'you'}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `itertools` recipes is the definition of `pairwise` which is useful to iterating a list 2 at a time:

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = it.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return a, b
```

You can use this to create a list of words that follow a word ending in `'.'`:

```
words = [n for m, n in zip(*pairwise(l)) if m[-1] == '.']
```

Remove duplicates:

```
seen = set()
results = [x for x in words if not (x in seen or seen.add(x))]
```