# Split a list of strings into their individual characters Python

Tags: python, split

Let's say I have a list:

```
list = ['foo', 'bar', 'bak']
```

I want to split these strings into their characters so I can assign values to each character (I.E. f = 5, o = 15, and so on).

How might I decompose these lists? 
I was thinking of turning each element into its own list, and referring to each element as an item of that list, but I am not sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: `newlist = [list(item) for item in list]`

Comment: @Sraw ... since the questioner has overwritten the definition of the `list` type with a variable also foolishly called `list`, your suggestion might not quite work as intended.

Comment: @donkopotamus Yea, you are right...

Comment: `reduce(str.__add__, list)`

Comment: N.B. that @Zefick 's `reduce` function is `functools.reduce` in Py3, and `''.join(mylist)` is much better optimized :)

Comment: BTW, [avoid using `list` as a variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31087111/4518341).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are iterable in Python, so you can just loop through them like this:

```
list = ['foo', 'bar', 'bak']

for item in list:
    for character in item:
        print(character)
```

Comment: That's not actually true in Python, but you can usually *pretend* they are and use them anyway (as in your example code). If a string were a list, you could do `"hello".extend(" world!")`. Contrast with some languages like Haskell where it's literally just a type alias `type String = [Char]`

Comment: This works! Thanks! Do you have a recommendation for distinguishing different strings from one another?

Comment: Strings are **not** "technically lists".  They're [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterable), that's different.

Comment: @donkopotamus I updated my answer to reflect what you and said; thanks for pointing it out to me.

Comment: @Sam I'm not entirely sure what you mean by distinguishing strings from one another, but if you mean in the `for character in item` loop, you can just use `item` inside of it to find what string you're looping over.

Comment: I figured out the "string distinguishent"- I upvoted this one because it was the simplest, easiest to read, and easiest to implement.

Answer (score 0):

If This Is What Your Looking For Here You Go:

```
listItems = ['foo', 'bar', 'bak']
listLetter = []
myDictionary = {}

for item in listItems:
    for letter in item:
        listLetter.append(letter)

myDictionary['f'] = 5

print myDictionary
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's what you want to convert into list of characters:

```
l = ['foo', 'bar', 'bak']

list(''.join(l))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one line solution :

```
list1 = ['foo', 'bar', 'bak']
print([j for i in list1 for j in i])
```

result :

```
['f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r', 'b', 'a', 'k']
```

Answer (score -1):

Join the entire list to each character

my_list = ['foo', 'bar', 'bak']

result = list(''.join(my_list))

result

['f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r', 'b', 'a', 'k']

now you can iterate through result to assign value to each character