# Python class return TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, class

I have a class:

```
class mountain:
  def __init__(self,pk_positions,chann_1,chann_2): 
    self.pk_positions = pk_positions
    self.chann_1 = chann_1
    self.chann_2 = chann_2
  def chann_1_pk(self):
    return(list(self.chann_1[i] for i in self.pk_positions))
  def chann_2_pk(self):
    return(list(self.chann_2[i] for i in self.pk_positions))
  def vall_positions(self):
    return(list(int((i+j)/2) for i,j in zip(self.pk_positions[:-1],self.pk_positions[1:])))
  def vall_sum(self):
    return(list(self.chann_1[i]+self.chann_2[i] for i in self.vall_positions()))
```

If I call in the main script:

```
peaks = mountain(pk_positions,chann_1,chann_2)
pk1 = peaks.chann_1_pk()   # ==> without error 
pk2 = peaks.vall_positions() # ==> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
pk3 = peaks.vall_sum()  # == > TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Why there is no error for pk1 but errors for pk2 and pk, please? 
I did some stackoverflow searching, but i don't think the problems is the naming of the defs and lists. Thanks.

Comment: Have you named a list `list` somewhere else in your code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31087111/typeerror-list-object-is-not-callable-in-python/31087151

Comment: Why are you using explicit calls to `list` instead of list comprehensions?

Comment: No i don't have a list named 'list'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this work?

```
list(int((i[0]+i[1])/2) for i in zip(self.pk_positions[:-1],self.pk_positions[1:]))
```

Your zip is returning something like [(0,1), (1,2), (2,3), (3,4)]

Your for loop is taking the first element of the zip (0,1)
And int is adding the two value of the list. (0 + 1) /2