# TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable - error

Tags: python, sql, pandas, tuples

```
engine = create_engine("")
df = pd.read_csv('in.csv', chunksize=1000) 
for chunk in df: 
    list= tuple(list(chunk["column2"])) 
    sql = "SELECT * from table where value in {};".format(list) 
    found = pd.read_sql(sql, engine) 
    found.to_csv('out.csv', mode='a', header ['column2'], index=False)
```

---

an error appeared and I'm not sure why and how to fix:

```
list= tuple(list(chunk["column2"]))
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Comment: Please do not name variables `list`.  It overrides a builtin python name and will lead to hard to find errors.

Comment: On the first iteration `tuple(list(chunk["column2"]))` works *and assigns its result to the name* `list`.  On the second iteration `list` is now a tuple, so the inner part `list(chunk["column2"])` is calling a tuple, not the builtin `list`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'list' object is not callable in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31087111/typeerror-list-object-is-not-callable-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a better approach - save your DF as a temporary (additional) table in your DB and use it for the subquery:

```
df[['column2']].to_sql('tmp', engine, if_exists='replace')
sql = """
SELECT * from table
where value in (select column2 from tmp)
"""
found = pd.read_sql(sql, engine)
```

or save it directly to CSV:

```
(pd.read_sql(sql, engine)
   .to_csv('out.csv', mode='a', header=['column2'], index=False))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are overwriting what `list` is.  You are assigning it to a tuple, and then calling it again, but instead of calling Python's builtin list, you are trying to call a tuple:

```
list = tuple(list((1,2)))   # this will work since you haven't reassigned list yet
list = tuple(list((2,3)))   # this will throw an error.
```