# 'TypeError: 'list' object is not callable' in ARIMA

Tags: list, range, arima

I am trying to launch a Python code for ARIMA prediction, but I have a problem with the following two lines

```
p = d = q = range(0, 2)
pdq = list(itertools.product(p, d, q))
```

When I run these basic two lines, the output is

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

What's the issue?

Comment: Impossible to say for sure from the truncated error and incomplete code, but you likely have a list called `list` somewhere else. Try `del list` before these lines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'list' object is not callable in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31087111/typeerror-list-object-is-not-callable-in-python)

Comment: no other list called "list" in the code.

Comment: Before the two lines that you posted here, write `print(type(list))` and run it. It could be `range` as well.