# How can I fix a problem about 'the list is not callable'

Tags: python, pandas, list

I am going to make a DataFrame but it had error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-3f0c40c312c9> in <module>
      9 #
     10 #
---> 11 df3 = pd.DataFrame([noteSeries, weekdaySeries]) #
     12 print(df3)

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

```
noteSeries = pd.Series(["C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "A", "B"],
    index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

weekdaySeries = pd.Series(["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"],
    index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

df3 = pd.DataFrame([noteSeries, weekdaySeries]) # 
print(df3)
```

Comment: Did you overwrite ``pd.DataFrame``?

Comment: Is there any code you're not showing? Most likely, you've replaced Python's `list` function with something else, or replaced `pd.DataFrame` with something else ! I.e. you've done `list = something`, or `pd.DataFrame = something` and of course now Pandas itself can't use `list` (it's not a function), or the `pd.DataFrame` is not a function, and everything is broken.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'list' object is not callable in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31087111/typeerror-list-object-is-not-callable-in-python)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, because the OP didn't overwrite the list here - most likely they overwrote DataFrame. Agreed, it is a similar problem

Comment: When asking such questions in the future, make sure you run the exact code you posted in the question, on a fresh python instance - i.e. so that we can reproduce it. Basically, make sure that the question is still valid if you took a break for a week, and then rebooted the computer :)

Comment: It is a duplicate problem. Thank you guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me as it is, with a couple of changes according to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

```py
import pandas as pd


noteSeries = pd.Series(
    ["C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "A", "B"],
    index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

weekdaySeries = pd.Series(
    ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"],
    index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

df3 = pd.DataFrame([noteSeries, weekdaySeries])
print(df3)
```

Try updating your version of pandas using the command line:

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
```

or

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pandas
```

If that doesn't fix it, then it's possible in your previous bit of code you have overwritten `pd.DataFrame` like this:

```py
pd.DataFrame = [1, 3, 5]
```

What this would do is it would make the DataFrame function into a normal list, which you then can't call as a function any more.

Comment: Thank you. Problem solved. I did not know that I should run in a fresh python instance.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark it as the solution by clicking the greyed-out arrow under the upvote/downvote arrows! Thanks :)