# About confusion_matrix() in sklearn

Tags: python, numpy

```
print(type(prediction))
print(type(np.array(testset_target)))
mat = confusion_matrix(np.array(testset_target),prediction)
```

output:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-ebab29cbd03f> in <module>
     23 print(type(prediction))
     24 print(type(np.array(testset_target)))
---> 25 mat = confusion_matrix(np.array(testset_target),prediction)
     26 confusion_matrix.append(mat)
     27 acc_sco=accuracy_score(prediction,testset_target)

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

They are both np.ndarray type, but why error said list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: 'list' object is not callable in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31087111/typeerror-list-object-is-not-callable-in-python)

Comment: did u declare any list earlier as confusion_matrix = []  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assigned `confusion_matrix` to something (a list). So `confusion_matrix` does not refer to the Sklearn function anymore, but to a list. So you can't "call" it. What gave it away is this line: `confusion_matrix.append(mat)`.

You can solve this problem if you change the name of your list and restart your program.

Comment: Really thank you. I didn't notice that. It is really helpful. Thank you very much!

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem