# calling functions in python 3 from within a function

Tags: string, function, python-3.6

Given a string, return the count of the number of times that a substring length 2 appears in the string and also as the last 2 chars of the string, so "hixxxhi" yields 1 (we won't count the end substring).

```
last2('hixxhi') → 1

last2('xaxxaxaxx') → 1

last2('axxxaaxx') → 2
```

I found this question in one of the websites (https://codingbat.com/prob/p145834).

The answer to the above question as given on the website is as follows :

```
def last2(str):
  # Screen out too-short string case.
  if len(str) < 2:
    return 0

  # last 2 chars, can be written as str[-2:]
  last2 = str[len(str)-2:]
  count = 0

  # Check each substring length 2 starting at i
  for i in range(len(str)-2):
    sub = str[i:i+2]
    if sub == last2:
      count = count + 1

  return count
```

I have a doubt on the below mentioned line of code

```
last2 = str[len(str)-2:]
```

Now, I know that this piece of code is extracting the last 2 letters of the string 'str'. What I am confused about is the variable name. As you can see that the variable name is same as the name of the function. So is this line calling the function again and updating the value of the variable 'str' ??

Comment: No, if it was calling the function again there'd be parentheses. It's just shadowing the name of the function with the local variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
def last2(str):
    . . .
```

This creates a parameter called `str` that shadows the built-in `str` class`*`. Within this function, `str` refers to the `str` parameter, not the `str` built-in class.

This is poor practice though. Don't name your variables the same thing as existing builtins. This causes confusing situations like this, and leads to issues like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31087111/typeerror-list-object-is-not-callable-in-python).

A better name would be something that describes what purpose the string has, instead of just a generic, non-meaningful `str`.

---

`*` The built-in `str` is actually a class, not a plain function. `str(x)` is a call to the constructor of the `str` class.

Answer (score 0):

```
def last2(str):
  if len(str) == 0:
    return 0
  last_two = str[-2::]
  
  count = 0
  for i in range(len(str)):
    if last_two == str[i :i + 2]:
      count += 1
    
  return count-1
```

this is the answer that was correct for me for the first time. The official answer is better, but this one might be less confusing for you.