# How do I get the indexes from the biggest to smallest number in a list?

Tags: python, list, indexing, max, min

I am coding a little project in Python:

I want to get the indexes (in a list) from the highest to smallest number in the following list:

```
list = [20, 30, 24, 26, 22, 10]
```

The outcome should be:

```
index_list = [1, 3, 2, 4, 0, 5]
```

Anyone has an idea of how I could do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is equivalent to generating the indices as a parallel list (which can be as simple as `list(range(len(x)))`, and then rearranging it in the same way that the original list would get sorted. Incidentally, [do not use `list`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31087111) as a name for the list, as that will prevent the parallel-list-making code from working :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Build the `index_list` in ascending index order, then call `sort()` with a `Comparator` that sorts descending by the value in the `list` at the given index.

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(20, 30, 24, 26, 22, 10);

List<Integer> index = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    index.add(i);
index.sort(Comparator.comparing(list::get).reversed());

System.out.println(index);
```

*Output*

```
[1, 3, 2, 4, 0, 5]
```

Or you can do it in one statement using streams, same result:

```
List<Integer> index = IntStream.range(0, list.size()).boxed()
                               .sorted(Comparator.comparing(list::get).reversed())
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: OP wrote: `I am coding a little project in Python`, this does not look like python?

Comment: hmmm, it's JAVA, when you change the input to `20, 10, 24, 26, 22, 10`, the output of your code is `[3, 2, 4, 0, 1, 5]`, and indeed my python thing says `[3, 2, 4, 0, 1, 1]`, remains my question how to do this in python... (but I will figure this out some day!)

Comment: your answer is in Java, not Python!

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty new to programming in python, but this seems to work:

```
list = [20, 30, 24, 26, 22, 10]
list_sorted = list.copy()
list_sorted.sort()

list_index = []
for x in list_sorted:
    list_index.insert(0,list.index(x))

print(list_index)
```

output:

```
[1, 3, 2, 4, 0, 5]
```

Because above will produce incorrect values it there are duplicates, see next:

```
list = [20, 10, 24, 26, 22, 10]
list_tmp = list.copy()
list_sorted = list.copy()
list_sorted.sort()

list_index = []
for x in list_sorted:
    list_index.insert(0,list_tmp.index(x))
    list_tmp[list_tmp.index(x)] = -1

print(list)
print(list_index)
```

output:

```
[20, 10, 24, 26, 22, 10]
[3, 2, 4, 0, 5, 1]
```

It should not matter if output is `[3, 2, 4, 0, 5, 1]` or `[3, 2, 4, 0, 1, 5]` because those indexes refer to the same values.

Comment: Won't work if there are duplicate values in the list. Also, performance is _O(n²)_, where a sort should be _O(n log(n))_

Comment: How should I do that? When there are duplicate values?

Comment: @Andreas do you have any idea?

Comment: @AntonisAsonitis I already gave [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59695470/5221149), and you already accepted it.

Comment: @AntonisAsonitis: I added a solution to take into account duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer isn't in Python and the other answer takes a few lines and isn't as fast as it could be for bigger datasets, so I thought I'd throw my hat in the ring:

```
import numpy as np

list = [20, 30, 24, 26, 22, 10]
index_list = np.array(list).argsort().tolist()[::-1]
```

The output is indeed:

```
index_list = [1, 3, 2, 4, 0, 5]
```

It handles indices for duplicate values, and it's very fast. It requires an import, but if you're dealing with big datasets chances are it'll have other functionality you need anyway and it'll save time overall.

Comment: using keyword `list` as a variable name seems very bad form

Comment: Agreed, but it's OP's nomenclature