# Getting Error in Pyspark - TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, pyspark

Note - Please note that I have already looked at recommendations in the answer for similar questions.
and I do not have a variable named List.

Basically I am trying to make sure that the number of elements in each row of my rdd are constant so that I can apply a uniform schema on the rdd
This is the code I am trying to run when I get the error. This used to work about until a month ago.

`tag0620_selected = tag0620_selected.map(lambda x: tuple([x[i] if i < len(x) else None for i in range(30)]))`

Here is a sample of two of the rows from the rdd on which I am trying to run this code:

`[(0, 45, 'TAG0620', '4D6J9ISKF08KB', '', '', 'O', '1', '3EX4F5S3MB4OU', 'Bremerhaven', '', '2U4AD56P1LNIY', 'NTB North SEA Terminal Bremerhaven', '1PLJ5T7MFKBJY', 'Germany', '', '', '', '', '2020-02-06 17.07.45', 'JWA207', '2020-02-06 17.07.45', 'JWA207', '30EJA7RKPF1J2', 'Bremen', 'HB', 'DE', 'DEBRV', 'DEBRVTM'), (0, 47, 'TAG0620', 'SYIK9ISKF08KB', '', '', 'O', '2', '1JUKNJGWHQBNJ', 'Rotterdam', '', '2LME4YKE32WZJ', 'APM Terminals Rotterdam', '0QKGIC8VAS51A', 'Netherlands', '', '', '', '', '2020-02-06 17.07.45', 'JWA207', '2020-02-06 17.07.45', 'JWA207', '2ON031AD5FX4U', 'Zuid-Holland', 'ZH', 'NL', 'NLROT', 'NLROT01')]`

Comment: Have you done `len = ...`, `tuple = ...`  or `range = ...` somewhere in your code?

Comment: Yes !! I never realized it would complain about List in that case ! Thank You !!

Comment: It complains because you overshadowed one of those built-in types/functions with a list, and you can't call a list object with `()`. You would have got a similar error with `int`

Comment: Oh now it makes sense , And I thought it had something to do with the rdd itself

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: 'list' object is not callable in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31087111/typeerror-list-object-is-not-callable-in-python)

Comment: AMC no that question didnt answer it but the comments from DeepSpace above did