# TypeError: ("'list' object is not callable", 'occurred at index 0')

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning

```
def create_tfidf_dictionary(x, transformed_file, features):

    vector_coo = transformed_file[x.name].tocoo()
    vector_coo.col = features.iloc[vector_coo.col].values
    dict_from_coo = dict(zip(vector_coo.col, vector_coo.data))
    return dict_from_coo

def replace_tfidf_words(x, transformed_file, features):

    dictionary = create_tfidf_dictionary(x, transformed_file, features)   
    return list(map(lambda y:dictionary[f'{y}'], x.title.split()))
%%time
replaced_tfidf_scores = file_weighting.apply(lambda x: replace_tfidf_words(x, transformed, features), axis=1)
```

**while running this code I'm having following error.**

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in apply(self,
>   func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, result_type, args, **kwds)    6911
>   kwds=kwds,    6912         )
>   -> 6913         return op.get_result()    6914     6915     def applymap(self, func):
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in get_result(self)
>       184             return self.apply_raw()
>       185 
>   --> 186         return self.apply_standard()
>       187 
>       188     def apply_empty_result(self):
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in
>   apply_standard(self)
>       290 
>       291         # compute the result using the series generator
>   --> 292         self.apply_series_generator()
>       293 
>       294         # wrap results
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in
>   apply_series_generator(self)
>       319             try:
>       320                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
>   --> 321                     results[i] = self.f(v)
>       322                     keys.append(v.name)
>       323             except Exception as e:
>
> in (x)
>
> in replace_tfidf_words(x,
>   transformed_file, features)
>        24     '''
>        25     dictionary = create_tfidf_dictionary(x, transformed_file, features)
>   ---> 26     return list(map(lambda y:dictionary[f'{y}'], x.title.split()))
>
> TypeError: ("'list' object is not callable", 'occurred at index 0')

I'm new to python, please help me out to this error.

Comment: Please improve the formatting of your question. Its difficult to see what is going on. In particular I don't know what the `%%time` line is doing.

Comment: Check your code way before this - I believe you may have `list = ` somewhere, thus overwriting the build-in name (`'list' object is not callable` suggests the name `list` is not a callable - when it normally should be).

Comment: Check this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31087111/typeerror-list-object-is-not-callable-in-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: 'list' object is not callable in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31087111/typeerror-list-object-is-not-callable-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

This is a common error, it usually happens when you set some value to a variable named `list`. Consider the code below:

```
list = [1+1, 2-4, 3*2]
values = list(1)
```

At the first line, we assign a value to the variable named `list`. That is kind of intuitive, because, well, if we have a *list*, why not putting it in a variable named `list`, right? However, at the second line, we try to call the function `list()`. However, we replaced the value of the variable `list`, it is not the function anymore, it is some other thing. The result is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sl.py", line 3, in <module>
    values = list(1)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

In your example, it is clear that you try to call the function at this line:

```
return list(map(lambda y:dictionary[f'{y}'], x.title.split()))
```

The challenge is to find where you assign a value to the `list` variable. As someone commented, you can look for the `list =` substring in your code, and change the name of the variable there for something different from `list`. If you do not find this snippet anywhere, you can replace

```
return list(map(lambda y:dictionary[f'{y}'], x.title.split()))
```

by

```
print(list)
```

It will show which value you have on the `list` variable and may help you figure out where it was changed.

Either way, you will have to search beyond the snippet you've posted to us, which can be a challenge.