# Python : "TypeError","evalue":"'list' object is not callable"

Tags: python, pyspark

I have python code which keeps giving below error. To the surprise it keeps coming in one environment (QA) but does not happen in another (DEV) inspite of using exact same code and input file

```
"TypeError","evalue":"'list' object is not callable"
```

I have below lines related to python list in my code -

```
country_list = list(input_df.select('country').distinct().toPandas()['country'])
country_list = list(filter(None, country_list)) 
country_code =  str(country_list).strip('[]')
```

Which looks fine to me and works in DEV environment without any issue. What could be the possible reason for this. Can this be something to with python versions?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: 'list' object is not callable in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31087111/typeerror-list-object-is-not-callable-in-python)

Comment: nope. I don't have any variable assigned to keyword like list in my code

Comment: Is there any other code which is running before your code?

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)