# Update list of objects to new object composed of items of list in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've converted a dict of values to a list of DynamoDB condition equals objects:

```
    list = []
    for key, value in values.items():
        list.append(Key(key).eq(value))
    print(list)
```

I have a list and it looks like this (It can be more then 2 items)

```
[<boto3.dynamodb.conditions.Equals object at 0x7fbe73a98d30>, <boto3.dynamodb.conditions.Equals object at 0x7fbe73a98df0>]
```

How can I convert this to

```
<boto3.dynamodb.conditions.Equals object at 0x7fbe73a98d30> & <boto3.dynamodb.conditions.Equals object at 0x7fbe73a98df0>
```

So I want to replace `','` by `'&'` and I want to keep the type of the boto3 dynamodb conditions equals object

After that I would be able to us it here

```
        response = self.table.query(
            IndexName=index,
            KeyConditionExpression=TheNewObject
        )
```

This is a working example:

```
        response = self.table.query(
            IndexName='Tracked-Index',
            KeyConditionExpression=Key('type').eq(sort) & Key('tracked').eq(tracked)
        )
```

Comment: What do you mean by "replace `,` with `&`?  Do you want to perform the `&` operation (bitwise and) on the elements?  Did you mean to do a "normal" `and` operation?

Comment: Good question, I'm actually not sure. See above for what I want to use it, so I think the operation can be performed already? Not sure actually.. I've updated my question with additional information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to apply a bitwise AND (`&`) to all items of the list in sequence. You can use [`operator.and_`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.and_) as a function that does bitwise AND, and [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) to apply the function.

```
L = [Key(key).eq(value) for key, value in values.items()]  # Comp instead of loop

from functools import reduce
from operator import and_
TheNewObject = reduce(and_, L)
```

For a dead-simple example:

```
>>> reduce(and_, [3, 5, 9])
1
```

BTW, [don't use `list` as a variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31087111/4518341) since it shadows the builtin.