# string to list and list to string conversion - without split

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, converters

Could you share how to convert string to list and vice versa as shown below (without splitting each words)

- Input: string `'I am a boy'`
- Output: `['I am a boy']`

and

- Input: list `['I am a boy']`
- Output: string `'I am a boy'`

Just to be clear, The first part is pretty straightforward and did  implemented before the post. I just stuck for the 2nd problem.

Comment: Can you please just include that text *as text* instead of a giant image?

Comment: Are you asking how you can create a list with one item? And how you get an item out of a list?

Comment: @mkrieger1 thanks for checking. I have pandas dataframe with one columns with text. I need to interate each rows of string and pass to google translate.. for google translate, it need input  (each rows ) to be ['I am a boy'] format . After translating each rows, need to have each row with original format yet google translated text Hope I did explain well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String to list (supposing it's a list with just 1 string, as per your image)

```py
inp = 'I am a boy'
lst = [input]
```

List to string (supposing it's a list with just 1 element of type string)

```py
inp = ['I am a boy']
string = input[0]
```

If you want to force casting (maybe cause you have a list of integers), you can use the `str()` function, such as `str(inp[0])` where `inp[0]` is maybe a number

Comment: Avoid overriding the names of buitins, cause it can cause confusing situations like this: [TypeError: 'list' object is not callable in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31087111/4518341). Instead of `input`, for example you could use `inp`, and instead of `list`, `L`.

Answer (score 1):

To "convert" a string to a list, you can just place it in one, e.g., by creating a new list with `[]`:

```py
input1 = 'I am a boy'
output1 = [input1]
```

To "convert" a list like you have to a string, you could simply extract the first and only value in it:

```py
input2 = ['I am a boy']
output2 = input2[0]
```

Comment: To clarify, there's no conversion involved here. This is putting a string into a list and taking it back out.

Comment: Yes, I did already the first part before posting. It is tricky for the second de-conversion