# Got an error: 'list' object is not callable in Python

Tags: python, list, class

I want to get a list of car brand (arr_1) based on an existing list (arr_0). Here is my code:

```py
class Keywords:
    def __init__(self):
        self.brand = ["kia", "hyundai", "mitsubishi", "honda", "toyota", "ford", "nissan", "suzuki", "vinfast", "mazda"]
    def classifyOldKeywords(self, arr_0, type):
        arr_copy = []
        arr_copy = [arr_0[i] for i in range(len(arr_0))]
        arr_for_type = []
        [arr_for_type.insert(0, arr_copy.pop(i)) for i in range(len(arr_copy)-1, -1, -1) if (arr_copy[i].lower() in type)]
        return arr_for_type
arr_0 = ['VinFast', 'Lux A', 'VinFast', 'Lux A', 'VinFast', 'VinFast', 'Lux A', 'VinFast', 'VinFast', 'Lux A', 'VinFast', 'Lux A', 'VinFast', 'sedan', 'VinFast', 'VinFast', 'Fadil', 'Lux A', 'Lux SA', 'Lux A']
arr_1 = Keywords().classifyOldKeywords(arr_0, Keywords().brand)
print(arr_1)
```

It returns an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "final.py", line 80, in <module>
    arr_copy = [arr_0[i] for i in range(len(arr_0))]
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: 'list' object is not callable in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31087111/typeerror-list-object-is-not-callable-in-python)

Comment: As already stated in a comment under another question, this is certainly caused because `len` or `range` has been used as the name of a list before. We can't tell more as we don't have the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason for using a class in this case?
The way I see it (correct me if I'm wrong):

- You have a list of cars
- You have a list of car brands
- You want to print a list containing cars that matches cars in the list of brands

If so, this could be one way to do it:

```py
carList = ["VinFast", "Lux A", "VinFast", "Lux A", "VinFast", "VinFast", "Lux A", "VinFast", "VinFast", "Lux A", "VinFast", "Lux A", "VinFast", "sedan", "VinFast", "VinFast", "Fadil", "Lux A", "Lux SA", "Lux A"]
brandList = ["kia", "hyundai", "mitsubishi", "honda", "toyota", "ford", "nissan", "suzuki", "vinfast", "mazda"]
matchList = []

[ matchList.append(car) for car in carList if car.lower() in map(str.lower, brandList) ]

# If brandList is always lowercase
# [ matchList.append(car) for car in carList if car.lower() in brandList ]

print(matchList)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this :

arr_copy = arr_0.copy()