# How to reference a module scoped variable as function argument

Tags: python

I have several modules that have the same variable of same name in each.  I am trying to write a function that can accept the name of the variable then sum its value over all of the modules.  I need to do this because this is the case for several variables.

For example, I have modules `moduleA`, `moduleB`, and `moduleC` that each have within them `var1`, `var2`, and `var3`.  I want to write a function that can accept the variable name, say `var1` as an argument then calculate:

```
sum = moduleA.var1 + moduleB.var2 + moduleC.var3
```

and return the value of `sum`.

I tried several different ways but kept getting an error that the module does not contain that name.  I have included my most recent attempt and the error below.

```
def sumYearly(name):
    sum = january.name + february.name
    return sum
```

where `january` and `february` are the names of modules and `name` is the variable I'm trying to use to pass in the variable that exists inside each module.  This results in the following error message:

```
    sum = january.name + february.name
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: how do you import modules?

Comment: Avoid naming variable after reserved words `sum`

Comment: @Joshua For example, here's an issue that came up after shadowing a builtin: [TypeError: 'list' object is not callable in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31087111/4518341). BTW, `sum` is not a keyword, just a builtin. Keywords can't be assigned to, like `None` and `if`.

Comment: @İsmailDurmaz - I am using the following format: from january import january . the module has same name as folder so thats why january shows up twice.

Comment: @JoshuaNixon - thanks for the advice.  I am still new to Python so I will keep that in mind for future reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) to dynamically retrieve the value of a variable defined in another module.
Assuming `january` and `february` to be two imported modules, then your function becomes:

```
def sumYearly(name):
    return getattr(january, name) + getattr(february, name)
```

Comment: Thanks.  That worked perfectly!  Thanks for taking the time to provide such a detailed answer and example.