# Wikipedia scraper Finding a list of articles and appending them to a dataframe Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, wikipedia, wiki

I am using Wiki scraper to search for every word of text in a text file and append the article through the dataframe.
I can do this manually but I want it to run through a for loop. Here is what i have:

```
    import requests
    import wikipedia
    text = list('boy', 'dog', 'service', 'navy')

    df = []
    for x in text():
         wiki = wikipedia.page(x)
         df.append(wiki.content)
```

That gives me a type error though `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: 'list' object is not callable in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31087111/typeerror-list-object-is-not-callable-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list` is a built-in python method. Notice how it is being highlighted in orange. You can utilize `list` in the same way you created the desired list above (shown below).  Your for loop is not working because you are calling the method rather than your list.

```
test_list = list('boy', 'dog', 'service', 'navy')

for x in test_list:
    do_thing()
```

Thus:

`list('boy', 'dog', 'service', 'navy')` is the same as `['boy', 'dog', 'service', 'navy']` and `list()` is the same as any basic function.

Comment: Hi sorry I actually was using different variable names I just changed them in here for simplicity.

Comment: With your edit, you are specifying text as a function with the brackets at the end. Remove the brackets like in my example and the loop should initiate.

Comment: more specifically `for x in text():` should be `for x in text:`