# How to count numbers

Tags: python, random

I want to be able to count how much 1,2,3...100s are on my list.
I tried a for loop, but it didn't work.
Code:

```
import os
import random
list = [1, 2]

# print numbers

list.insert(1, random.randrange(100))

for x in range(1000):
  list.insert(1, random.randrange(100))

print(list)
```

output:

```
PS C:\Users\regok> & C:/Users/regok/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/Users/regok/Desktop/VFIDG/gui.py
[1, 45, 76, 12, 27, 46, 85, 43, 79, 62, 95, 6, 51, 23, 57, 12, 34, 72, 12, 8, 89, 89, 31, 12, 19, 19, 42, 11, 62, 41, 74, 39, 16, 6, 57, 75, 15, 46, 98, 3, 54, 57, 66, 92, 88, 79, 70, 89, 67, 12, 54, 93, 56, 40, 9, 84, 5, 41, 8, 63, 50, 41, 79, 48, 6, 80, 63, 95, 7, 15, 9, 91, 23, 95, 6, 22, 99, 12, 45, 6, 43, 78, 13, 21, 69, 0, 8, 45, 71, 13, 18, 89, 89, 60, 57, 58, 13, 4, 95, 38, 86, 95, 34, 77, 15, 31, 81, 6, 43, 79, 15, 74, 86, 53, 30, 63, 43, 95, 13, 50, 61, 75, 21, 81, 17, 42, 40, 81, 9, 1, 74, 26, 97, 75, 77, 
32, 40, 44, 70, 52, 46, 35, 94, 34, 84, 64, 28, 8, 70, 69, 51, 11, 29, 68, 36, 67, 57, 82, 49, 44, 6, 30, 91, 19, 36, 13, 2, 63, 33, 34, 49, 47, 5, 32, 48, 27, 64, 42, 17, 96, 5, 68, 20, 95, 1, 40, 52, 49, 37, 90, 92, 9, 75, 30, 96, 66, 30, 54, 70, 6, 83, 63, 44, 93, 88, 4, 42, 99, 96, 11, 75, 73, 9, 23, 63, 32, 57, 75, 66, 27, 46, 4, 13, 8, 82, 69, 90, 65, 27, 61, 36, 84, 94, 26, 2, 60, 83, 8, 31, 0, 29, 16, 1, 66, 56, 22, 38, 69, 16, 66, 70, 36, 24, 24, 70, 61, 20, 89, 18, 54, 64, 47, 53, 18, 65, 6, 21, 83, 3, 11, 
0, 55, 63, 17, 67, 14, 64, 62, 2, 15, 18, 76, 10, 63, 86, 44, 8, 92, 70, 91, 90, 92, 44, 21, 91, 65, 82, 88, 32, 81, 45, 14, 65, 68, 20, 53, 9, 70, 7, 32, 4, 31, 43, 97, 49, 10, 51, 74, 24, 35, 18, 81, 65, 18, 82, 12, 26, 41, 56, 55, 34, 72, 61, 71, 9, 40, 51, 
82, 46, 73, 16, 24, 65, 59, 93, 8, 8, 0, 52, 48, 32, 75, 6, 93, 85, 33, 48, 17, 1, 82, 28, 19, 20, 34, 75, 89, 65, 12, 11, 58, 11, 41, 87, 79, 96, 74, 13, 89, 66, 37, 34, 20, 30, 70, 41, 77, 20, 58, 1, 80, 21, 25, 37, 51, 74, 0, 57, 5, 23, 22, 64, 46, 1, 23, 79, 38, 96, 33, 58, 25, 49, 22, 87, 65, 70, 8, 64, 70, 24, 37, 97, 86, 79, 21, 27, 32, 82, 20, 59, 49, 26, 71, 12, 41, 73, 18, 90, 28, 72, 34, 2, 73, 51, 49, 93, 26, 1, 16, 53, 51, 71, 54, 76, 48, 26, 57, 9, 37, 93, 58, 90, 7, 78, 4, 32, 27, 79, 45, 93, 19, 23, 91, 28, 57, 56, 88, 32, 94, 90, 6, 20, 99, 26, 50, 20, 41, 61, 2, 50, 92, 16, 12, 2, 30, 67, 96, 23, 48, 85, 37, 70, 6, 82, 23, 7, 23, 56, 96, 15, 70, 16, 38, 50, 5, 84, 48, 51, 54, 4, 41, 28, 19, 35, 27, 30, 89, 22, 75, 48, 97, 29, 71, 64, 15, 43, 98, 71, 34, 68, 36, 96, 78, 49, 60, 86, 34, 3, 54, 44, 42, 23, 38, 80, 93, 95, 76, 63, 93, 77, 56, 11, 5, 4, 95, 36, 77, 1, 73, 73, 52, 72, 51, 3, 3, 74, 93, 16, 13, 58, 56, 52, 6, 47, 0, 88, 77, 85, 77, 9, 93, 89, 61, 78, 9, 70, 43, 46, 46, 38, 16, 84, 38, 65, 4, 63, 64, 60, 28, 90, 40, 79, 62, 57, 75, 28, 43, 42, 85, 95, 78, 7, 18, 49, 69, 96, 53, 77, 27, 92, 33, 69, 8, 36, 23, 16, 59, 97, 4, 73, 61, 46, 99, 92, 8, 81, 36, 46, 42, 59, 27, 63, 21, 76, 23, 44, 89, 88, 36, 69, 30, 89, 34, 32, 74, 41, 45, 81, 57, 74, 26, 16, 58, 66, 76, 11, 7, 66, 26, 28, 92, 20, 90, 42, 4, 39, 50, 99, 46, 48, 73, 73, 14, 56, 92, 49, 20, 90, 75, 26, 14, 58, 44, 99, 54, 55, 66, 3, 13, 28, 44, 72, 5, 78, 7, 90, 62, 35, 70, 69, 65, 84, 68, 30, 22, 85, 2, 58, 99, 96, 46, 28, 83, 59, 55, 31, 5, 84, 39, 14, 76, 45, 39, 3, 27, 92, 18, 46, 62, 84, 59, 86, 74, 8, 51, 12, 12, 53, 2, 51, 19, 97, 93, 84, 15, 42, 65, 4, 85, 86, 95, 23, 37, 33, 38, 67, 51, 9, 17, 17, 84, 70, 45, 2, 57, 50, 64, 88, 22, 28, 10, 95, 26, 71, 7, 6, 3, 95, 11, 67, 7, 29, 74, 39, 36, 20, 68, 38, 85, 39, 1, 13, 24, 58, 51, 16, 95, 73, 38, 64, 96, 13, 44, 65, 78, 55, 39, 73, 65, 60, 83, 37, 66, 37, 99, 57, 25, 13, 48, 66, 13, 29, 91, 40, 37, 5, 45, 26, 98, 46, 38, 91, 57, 94, 74, 43, 83, 19, 27, 63, 57, 54, 20, 32, 21, 34, 1, 88, 95, 3, 99, 1, 31, 23, 98, 22, 22, 22, 82, 45, 56, 9, 65, 18, 67, 32, 31, 10, 89, 93, 44, 51, 19, 35, 77, 21, 68, 22, 1, 21, 16, 39, 23, 31, 74, 86, 84, 4, 51, 63, 54, 67, 16, 93, 71, 20, 83, 51, 55, 7, 47, 28, 20, 61, 3, 23, 7, 19, 60, 16, 48, 34, 0, 63, 58, 53, 58, 42, 26, 78, 46, 95, 96, 15, 13, 69, 18, 18, 35, 81, 67, 52, 26, 88, 18, 86, 74, 30, 44, 74, 81, 78, 25, 39, 47, 66, 45, 72, 29, 32, 56, 77, 68, 14, 51, 54, 23, 41, 20, 66, 60, 85, 92, 37, 49, 23, 20, 22, 25, 90, 41, 12, 98, 5, 36, 73, 40, 28, 71, 22, 52, 76, 33, 2]
PS C:\Users\regok>
```

the code I tried to count with:

```
#count numbers

for 1 in list:
  print("there is 1")
```

Comment: Please don't use `list` as a variable name in python.

Comment: `for 1 in ...` is invalid syntax

Comment: Sidenote, `list` is a bad variable name since it shadows the builtin. See [TypeError: 'list' object is not callable in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31087111/4518341)

Comment: What's your desired output? Please provide a [mre]. See [ask] if you want more tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change for loop like this

```
for i in list:
  if i==1:
    print("there is 1")
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.  Perhaps explain *how* you believe this answer can help the OP.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could do this without a loop.

In the code below I've used two - Counter from [collections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) and [value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) from Pandas.

```
import random
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

number_list = [1, 2]

# print numbers

number_list.insert(1, random.randrange(100))

for x in range(1000):
  number_list.insert(1, random.randrange(100))

print(number_list)

count_collections = Counter(number_list)

print(count_collections)

count_pandas = pd.Series(number_list).value_counts()

print(count_pandas)
```

Comment: Please update the answer to use a variable name other than `list` as this is overwriting the builtin type.  (Please encourage OP to do the same; by taking this opportunity to teach, not just giving an answer.). Additionally, `value_counts`, and `pandas` in general, is *way* overkill for this simple task.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use the `count()` method on your list:

```
for x in range(101):
    print(x, "was found", mylist.count(x), "times")
```

Result:

```
0 was found 1 times
1 was found 2 times
2 was found 2 times
3 was found 0 times
4 was found 3 times
5 was found 0 times
.
.
.
98 was found 0 times
99 was found 0 times
100 was found 1 times
```

Comment: OP's data includes 0s, which this won't count. Either way, this would be done better by a `Counter`

Comment: @wjandrea it counted 0s but it also counted past 100. I fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I hope that I understood your problem correctly: You want to count the sum from 1 to 100? If so, i don't understand what you want to do with 'random'.
There a different ways.

Option 1:

```
counter = 0
for i in range(0, 101):
    counter += i
print(counter)
```

Option 2: if you want to use a list:

```
mylist = []
for i in range(101):
    mylist.append(i)
print(mylist)
print(sum(mylist))
```

EDITION: I think to understand your question:
First: As others said, please rename your variable list.
A possible solution to count the random numbers of the list is to create a dicitionary:

```
counter_dict = {}
for element in mylist:
    if element in counter_dict.keys():
        counter_dict[element] += 1
    else:
        counter_dict.update({element : 1})
for key in counter_dict:
    print('The number {} is {} times in mylist'.format(str(key), str(counter_dict[key]))
```

Comment: Hi! I would like to be able to count how much 1's are in my list, 2's, 3's to 100, and then print out them

Comment: Or, more simply: `x = n(n+1)/2`.  In either case, I believe the question was misunderstood.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but FWIW, the best option is: `counter = sum(range(1, 101))`. BTW, avoid `int()`, write `0` instead.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using a Dictionary to keep a tally of all the counts, something like this:

```
import os
import random
from collections import Counter
list = [1, 2]

# print numbers

list.insert(1, random.randrange(100))

for x in range(1000):
  list.insert(1, random.randrange(100))

#print(list)

#count numbers
cnt = Counter()

for x in list:
    cnt[x] += 1
    
#print number of 1's seen:
print(cnt[1])
```

@wjandrea: Thank you, I've updated my answer using the Dictionary Subclass Counter.

Comment: There's already a tool for doing this in the standard library: [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: You could condense that if-statement down to: `counted[x] = counted.get(x, 0) + 1`. Note that capitalized names should only be used for classes.