# How to find all possible sequences within a list of lists in python?

Tags: python

I am unsure how to return all possible sequences within a list of lists. It is important that the index in the main list corresponds to the position in the sequence.

Input:

```
list = [["Lys", "Arg"],['Gly'],["Phe", "Tyr"]]
```

Output:

```
["Lys", "Gly", "Phe"]
["Arg", "Gly", "Phe"]
["Lys", "Gly", "Tyr"]
["Arg", "Gly", "Tyr"]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `list` is not a variable name. It is a type. Don't overwrite it.

Comment: @Kraigolas *[shadow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing), not overwrite. But yes, you're right. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31087111/4518341) for an example of what can happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import itertools

x = []
a = [["Lys", "Arg"],['Gly'],["Phe", "Tyr"]]
for i in itertools.product(*a):
    x.append(i)
ll2 = [list(y) for y in x]
print (*ll2)
```

Comment: I think I see what you're saying however your output provides a list of tuples.

Comment: That for-loop is unnecessary. Just use `x = list(itertools.product(*a))`. To convert the elements to list, you could do `x = list(map(list, itertools.product(*a)))`

Comment: sorry, i edited my comment but that was confusing so I deleted it and reposted