# Getting First Element in Nested List

Tags: python, python-3.x

Okay so let's say I have a list similar to this:

```
list = ['1', 'a', 11, 'aa'],
     ['2', 'b', 22, 'bb']
```

I only want the string '1' to print.

If I use:

```
for sublist in list:
       print(sublist[0])
```

I get '1' and '2', but I only want '1' to display. Any suggestions?

Comment: `df[0][0]`? BTW, why are you calling it a df? That's not a [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html).

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: Changed it to list, sorry, pretty new to all this.

Comment: Beside the point, but avoid `list` as a variable name since it shadows the builtin `list`. [Here's an example of the confusion it can cause.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31087111/4518341)

Comment: That's not a list, that's a tuple and an indentation error.

Answer (score 1):

```
print(df[0][0])
```

Try this without for loop. Just this.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the for loop you will be iterating through all elements in `df`.

So here you have two options:

1. The simplest:

```
    print(df[0][0])
```

*Note that the first index is from the main list (df) and the second one is for the first sublist.*

2. If you want to have the for loop anyways:

```
    for sublist in df:
       if sublist == df[0]:
          print(sublist[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, by creating your list the way you did, you create a „tuple“ with two lists:

print(type(list))
<class 'tuple'>

Second: With your code for element in list... you are iterating through the tuple with the two nested lists. So sublist[0] prints the first element of the first list, and on a separate line the first element of the second list: you are looping through your tuple.

So use what client recommended. Access the first list (within your tuple) and then the first element within that list by print(list[0][0]). This should do the trick. Remember Python starts counting elements at index 0.

Comment: I did a bad job in describing this problem. I imported a CSV file and each row is a 'list', but each element inside the row is its own type, either str, int, etc. I just said the list like that to help describe it as I wasn't sure how else to describe it. Sorry for my poor details.

Comment: No worries. Is your problem solved now? If not why don't you post your complete code around this problem?

Comment: Yes it's resolved. I'm not entirely sure how to close my question though, if that's a thing.