# How to remove extra quotation marks from each element list in python

Tags: python, list

I have list in the form:

```
list=["'A'","'B'","'C'"]
```

and would like change this list to the form:

```
list=['A','B','C']
```

I have tried the following;

```
for i in list:
   str.replace("''",'')
```

however, this returned an error of "replace() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)"
I'd be grateful for any help on how to achieve the removing of quotation marks, or if anyone can tell me how to alter my code to make it successful.
Thank you.

Comment: `str` is a class, and `i` isn't used.

Comment: Beside the point, but `list` is a bad variable name since it [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the [builtin `list` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list). Use a more descriptive name, or at least something like `lst`. For an example, see [TypeError: 'list' object is not callable in python](/q/31087111/4518341).

Answer (score 2):

```py
[item.strip("'") for item in lst]
```

*Please note it's advisable to avoid naming lists 'list' and so the variable has been renamed to 'lst' here.

Comment: Another user has already posted this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68685961/how-to-remove-extra-quotation-marks-from-each-element-list-in-python/68685991#68685991)

Answer (score 1):

You can just `strip` off the quote at the beginning and end of the string, you can use list-comprehension to do it for each of the items:

```py
>>> [i.strip("'") for i in lst]
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a [`method` of the `str` builtin class/type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) instead of calling it for an instance. Use `i.replace(...)` instead.

Why it happens? Because a method has a reserved first parameter (mostly named) `self` which is a reference to the class instance - in your case an instance of the [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) class. Since `str` is a builtin, thus generally available, you using that name are causing an access to that builtin i.e. to the `replace()` method, but not actually calling it properly.

```
# notice this
replace(self, ...)
```

```
Help on method_descriptor:

replace(self, old, new, count=-1, /)
    Return a copy with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new.
    
      count
        Maximum number of occurrences to replace.
        -1 (the default value) means replace all occurrences.
    
    If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are
    replaced.
```

You *can* however call it with `str.replace()` just fine - if you really want to - but you first need to supply the instance e.g. like this:

```py
str.replace(i, "''", '')
```

---

Also, mutability will play a role in here, so just calling it on a string this way will replace those characters, but won't save it back to the list, it'll just create a copy. Instead you'd need to use indexing:

```py
mylist = ["'A'","'B'","'C'"]
for idx, item in enumerate(mylist):
    list[idx] = item.replace("''", '')
```

And by this point it's still trying to remove two single-quotes, thus either replace only a single one (`replace("'", "")`) or use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68685991/5994041) with [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip).

Comment: :) Yup, SE supports limited HTML

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is remove the ' character from each element using the strip method:

```
for i in range(len(list)):
    list[i] = list[i].strip("'")
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `str` (the class) instead of `i` (the instance). The reason you're getting an error about the number of arguments is because there's an implicit first argument, `self`.

As well, strings aren't mutable, so you'll either need to assign back into the list by index or overwrite it, which I'd recommend since it's simpler.

#### Assign back

```
L = ["'A'", "'B'", "'C'"]
for idx, s in enumerate(L):
    L[idx] = s.replace("'", "")
print(L)  # -> ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

#### Overwrite

```
L = ["'A'", "'B'", "'C'"]
L[:] = [s.replace("'", "") for s in L]
print(L)  # -> ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

This uses a full-slice assignment so that you keep the same list object. If you don't mind replacing it, you can simplify it to this:

```
L = [s.replace("'", "") for s in L]
```

---

*Sidenote*: I'm using `L` because `list` is a bad variable name since it [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the [builtin `list` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list). C.f. [TypeError: 'list' object is not callable in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31087111/4518341)