# I want to read an external file with numbers and copy them into a list. Python

Tags: python, list, file, sorting

```
from io import open
files=open("file.txt","r")
list=files.readlines()
```

The file I have put contains numbers and I want to sort those numbers but it does not let
me because it takes it as a list of strings some idea or simple solution to solve this??

Comment: NIT: You don't need `io` for `open`. Also, use a `with` statement (e.g. `with open("file.txt") as f:`. This automatically closes the file for you. If you don't want to use `with`, you should close the file via `files.close()`.

Comment: Related: [How to read a file without newlines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/how-to-read-a-file-without-newlines)

Comment: As a side note, "list" is not a good name for a list. See, for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55115952/5785250

Answer (score 0):

just cast the read list of strings to numbers because files reads in python read as a string by default and you can always cast the string value to the needed typee

```
from io import open
file=open("file.txt","r")
list = []
for line in file.readlines():
  for item in line.split(' '):
    list.append(int(item))
```

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 20 13 14 15 16 16 17 18 19 20' its giving me this problem

Comment: you need to split every line to the separator character between numbers, it's a space in that case before casting it, I will modify my answer

Comment: also I am answering on general file reading cases, I need to know exactly the content of the file you want to read

Answer (score 0):

One way you can proceed ahead from here onwards is that you iterate over each list of strings you got after `list=files.readlines()` [please use a different name for your list as it currently coincides with the keyword list], is that you create separate empty list(s) l1 (,l2, l3, etc.) and iterate over your `list` and covert each string number into a integer number, like:

`for i in list:`

````
       ```l1.append(int(i))```
````

l1 will have all of the numbers now, in integer format.