# Compiler ERROR 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, list, compiler-errors

[image]
What is causing this compiler error?
How Could I fix this
This works on online editor

```
value = (10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
my_tuple = list(value)
print(my_tuple)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: 'list' object is not callable in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31087111/typeerror-list-object-is-not-callable-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that you've shadowed the built-in function "list". This would mean that you might have used the word "list" as a variable somewhere in your code.

For example:

```py
list = [1,232,3232]
value = (10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
my_tuple = list(value)
print(my_tuple)
```

I can see that you are using an *.ipynb* file so do take note that all blocks you run are saved so if you have "list" as a variable in another block which you have previously it would result in an error in this block.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message for a different error. I had:

```
for xx in this_list():
```

The parenthesis after "this_list" caused it. Hope it helps